# Get live car data from SUMO simulation to java

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, simulation

I currently have a openstreetmap converted to be used in sumo with 10000 cars and for an unlimited time. What we need to do as a school assignement is use this data and load it in to our existing application to test the scalability of the code we have written.
The question is how would I be able to load the info that is being generated per car into a seperate java application. I've tried searching for solutions but came up empty so far. I'm hoping that I just missed something and that this can be done.

Comment: Why do you flag this as python when you ask for Java?

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two approaches:

1. Parse the Sumo XML output while it is being written using a socket connection or a named pipe
2. Connect directly to Sumo using the TraCI4J or the TraaS interface.

For the first approach you need to open a server socket on the Java side

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

and then run Sumo directing the output to the socket. Assuming you run both on the same machine and you use emission output you should call

```
sumo -c my.sumocfg --emission-output localhost:12345
```

(You can of course choose a different port than 12345, but they have to match for both calls.)

Then you can parse the file reading from the BufferedReader, you will probably want to read something on XML parsing.

The second approach will involve [TraaS](http://traas.sf.net)

```
String sumo_bin = "c:/Program Files (x86)/sumo/bin/sumo-gui.exe";
String config_file = "simulation/config.sumo.cfg";
SumoTraciConnection conn = new SumoTraciConnection(sumo_bin, config_file);

conn.runServer();

//load routes and initialize the simulation
conn.do_timestep();

//get the CO2 emission for a specific vehicle
double co2 = (double) conn.do_job_get(Vehicle.getCO2Emission("v0"));
System.out.println("CO2: " + co2 + " g/s");

//stop TraCI
conn.close();
```

Please see the docs on [TraaS](http://traas.sf.net) and on the [Sumo outputs](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Output) for available methods and outputs

Comment: I'm trying to use the TraaS solution however I can't seem to find the option to get the longitude and latitude of the car. Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: Also I'm having a problem. It doesn't get past the conn.do_timestep() method. it does start up the gui and the output in the gui says that loading is done from that point on nothing will happen. Do you have any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: I am not too familiar with TraaS, but I suppose the convertGeo function http://sumo.dlr.de/daily/javadoc/traas/de/tudresden/sumo/cmd/Simulation.html#convertGeo-double-double-java.lang.String- could do the trick.

Comment: For the second problem, maybe a stupid question but did you start the simulation pressing the green play button?

Comment: Ohh damn the way I read the javadoc for the do_timestep() i figured it would start the simulation. Is it possible to make a call to start the simulation like that or not? I did start it twice by pressing the play button but that would then throw an error on the vehicle

Comment: You can start the sumo-gui with the `-S` switch to start immediately (or put `<start value="true"/>` in the config).